# Using some axioms from ZF for a proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using only the 1) Extensionality, 2)Pairset, 3) Empty-set , and 4) Seperation axioms from Zermelo-Fraenkel Set theory, prove the following.
For every non-empty set $X$, there exists a  subset of $X$,  $Y \subset X$, such that $Y \notin X$.

Edit: My attempt. Suppose not, so  that there exists a non-empty set $X$, such that if $Y \subseteq X$, then $Y \in X$ .
Since the empty set is a subset of every set, we have that $\emptyset \in X$. This in turn gives $\{ \emptyset \}  \subseteq X$, and by the property , we also have that $\{ \emptyset \}  \in X$. Repeating this procedue again we get $\{ \emptyset , \{ \emptyset\} \}  \in X$, and so on which means that $X$ must contain the von neumann natural numbers ?

Then (??) this violates axioms 1-4.

Comment: Unless $X$ is empty, of course.

Comment: Let me suggest you look at our guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on how to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your post is a simple problem statement, without any context at all, for example there is no mathematical discussion of your attempts to solve the problem. Such posts can quickly attract down votes.

Comment: Fixed that @J.G.

Comment: Your attempt would require $\exists x\in X(x\in x)$.

Comment: In your attempt, how do you conclude that $Y\not\in X$? And where did you use that $X$ is nonempty?

Comment: You might find a proof by contradiction feasible.

Comment: Is the claim even true? What if $X=\{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: @Karl Your example makes me rethink the validity of the claim

Comment: @Karl I read the question wrong, it doesn't have to be a proper subset.

Comment: Hmm, in your new attempt you aren't justified in taking $X=\{\emptyset\}$ after already taking $X$ to be something else.

Comment: @Karl the subset $X$ itself obeys $X \notin X$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Not necessarily true - we don’t assume foundation. Hint for OP: look up Russell’s paradox.

Comment: @MarkSaving I was refering to Karl's **specific** $X$ that he proposed as a potential counterexample (but which is not).

Comment: @MarkSaving Could you elaborate on the method using Russell's paradox ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Russell’s Paradox, which can be phrased as follows:

> Theorem: there is no set $X$ such that $\forall y (y \in X)$.

Proof: suppose there were such an $X$. Consider $V_X = \{x \in X \mid x \notin x\}$. Suppose $V_X \in V_X$. Then $V_X \notin V_X$ by the definition of $V_X$; contradiction. Therefore $V_X \notin V_X$. But we know that $V_X \in X$, and therefore $V_X \in V_X$ by the definition of $V_X$. This is a contradiction. $\square$

Now note that with a little cleverness and a very small modification of the proof, we can rephrase the theorem as

> Theorem: for all $X$, there is a $V_X \subseteq X$ such that $V_X \notin X$.